# Pandas fill in empty values based on the same ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Dataframe.

My first data But the second row, column B is missing a value.

[image]

My second data has this value in column B of the second row

[image]

I want the second data to fill the null value of the first data.

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

test1 ='test1.xlsx'
test2 ='test2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.excel(test1)
df2 = pd.excel(test2)

df3 = pd.merage(df1, df2, on='clolumns', how='left')

df3.to_excel('df3.xlsx')
```

The result will be columns2_X and columns2_Y , I want to merge into one column.

Comment: provide data in text not as image

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar hi, excel data structure, I don't know how to convert to text, if you have examples, can you tell me thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try `combine_first` function

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': [123, 1234, 12345], 'B' : ['str1', None, 'str3']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': [123, 1234, 12345], 'B' : [None, 'str2', None]})
>>> result = df1.combine_first(df2)
>>> result
       A     B
0    123  str1
1   1234  str2
2  12345  str3
```

Comment: hi, abhilb hi,  I test in excel also don't seem to work

Comment: hi,I removed the blank value row,
then merge
frames = [test1, test2]
result = pd.concat(frames)

Comment: It returns a new data frame so you need to assign it to a new variable

Answer (score 0):

#### One option is use `np.where`

```
df2['columns2_x'] = np.where(df2['columns2_x'] == '', df2['columns2_y'], df2['columns2_x'])
```

#### another option is to use `update` df1 with filetered df2

```
df1.update(df2[df2['columns1'].isin(df1[df1['columns2'] == '']['columns1'])])
```

Comment: hi,Prince Francis I tested both methods in excel but it doesn't seem to work and no errors are reported.